# Iterating over list of list of object

Tags: c++, list, stl

I want to iterate over a list of list of Object,

```
list<list<Point>> gnuPoints;
```

this is a static list which accepts list from various classes like circle and polygon all of which classes pushes multiple objects i.e Point(x,y) to the list

```
 while (angle != 360)
{
 double x = m_radius*cos(angle);
 double y = m_radius*sin(angle);
 angle += 30;
 circlePoint.push_back(Point(x, y));
}

similarly goes with Polygon and line shapes

polygonPoint.push_back(Point(x,y));
linePoint.Push_back(point(x,y));
```

then these lists are pushed in gnuPoint(list< list< Point> >).

```
gnuPoints.push_back(circlePoints);
gnuPoints.push_back(polygonPoints);
gnuPoints.push_back(linePoints);
```

now i want to write all these x,y values of different shapes in a file,
To iterate over it i cant find any particular solution after this code.

```
for (list<list<Point>>::iterator it = Point::gnuPoints.begin();
    it != Point::gnuPoints.end();
    it++)
{
//My assumption is that another For loop would come but could not apply 
  as I don't know what is available at the first index of gnuPoints list.
}
```

Comment: `for (auto inner_list : gnuPoints) { for (auto element : inner_list) { ... } }`?

Comment: As for ‘*I don't know what is available at the first index of gnuPoints*’: Yeah you do; it's a `list<Point>`.

Comment: yes its a list<Point> ,but i dont know if it's a CirclePoint or LinePoint because these list are pushed at runtime and order is not specific.

Comment: It's neither. It's just a `list<Point>`. Any other information is lost by then. If you need to differentiate the inner lists, perhaps a map would be better.

Comment: thanks it helped, yeah but would also like to know to use list of map of object.

Comment: thanks the list worked out, but would also like to know to use list of map of object. i.e. list<map<string,Point>>gnupoint  as my target is to differentiate between shape points in the file .   If this was the scenario how would i work it out with the inner for loop

Comment: I was thinking rather of a map of lists.

Comment: actually that can also work , what would be the login for iterating over map<string,list<Point>>

Answer (score 0):

```
for (list<list<Point>>::iterator it = Point::gnuPoints.begin();
    it != Point::gnuPoints.end();
    it++)
{
     for (list<Point>::iterator innerIt = it->begin(); innerIt != it->end(); ++innerIt)
}
```

If you are already on a compiler that supports c++11, this could be simply written as:

```
for (const auto& container : Point::gnuPoints)
{
    for (const auto& item : container)
    {
    }
}
```